# Github Wiki - Source code syntax highlighting

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, wiki

how can I write some code in my project github wiki and highlight the syntax?

In MoinMoin wiki I'm used to do

```
{{{#!highlight cpp
my code
}}}
```

and it work's great.

Any suggestion for github wiki?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You use "```"
Example for ruby:

````
```ruby
code and stuff
```
````

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know where can I find the list of available syntaxes?

Comment: @lucaghera I'm using this: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml

Comment: @lucaghera I don't think that feature exists in the wiki.